# how to calculate the dot product of two arrays of vectors in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, linear-algebra

`A and B` are both arrays with `shape(N,3)`. They each contain N vectors such that `A[0] = a0 (vector), A[1] = a1...` and `B[0] = b0, B[1] = b1...`

I want to calculate the dot product of the N pairs of vectors an and bn. In other words, I want to obtain an array C with `shape(N,1)` such that `C[i] = np.dot(A[i],B[i]).` What is the most efficient way of doing this in python (e.g. using vectorized code)?

Comment: For a physicist there's a surprising amount of hand waving in this problem description.  What have you tried, vectorized or not?  Small sample arrays would be nice.  The numpy dot tools are `np.dot`, `np.tensordot`, `np.einsum`, and the new `@`.

Comment: In case someone comes here 7 years after the question was asked the einsum idea is a good one but I find the documentation a bit confusing. I had the exact same problem: the inner product of N vectors row by row. To do this with einsum I found this to work `np.einsum('...j,...j',A,B)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can perform element-wise multiplication and then sum along the second axis, like so -

```
C = (A*B).sum(1)
```

These multiplication and summation operations can be implemented in one go with [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), like so -

```
C = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,B)
```

With [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html)/`@-operator` -

```
(A[:,None,:] @ B[...,None]).ravel()
```