# faster alternative to numpy einsum?

Tags: python, numpy, tensordot

I have two matrices - U and V with n vectors in each one as follows:

```
U = [u1, u2, u3,... un]
V = [v1, v2, v3,... vn]
```

(in fact U and V are 2d numpy arrays, the vectors u1..un, and v1...vn are 1d)

I want to create a 1d numpy array of n values:

```
W = [dot(u1, v1), dot(u2, v2), dot(u3, v3),..., dot(un, vn)]
```

(dot = dot product)

Currently I do this with numpy's einsum:

```
W = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', U, V)
```

However, my matrices are large and the calculation is repeated many times (with different U and V) so I try to find ways to make it faster.

I understand that there could be faster alternatives to np.einsum, like **np.dot** or **np.tensordot** or [einsum2](https://github.com/jackkamm/einsum2) that utilize parallelism (while  np.einsum is sequential). But I did not manage to get the same functionality - with both np.dot an np.tensordot the output is a 2d matrix that contains the result of more dot products than I need.

I also started to look at [NumExpr](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/user_guide.html) but didn't find a way to achieve what I need in an elegant way and without more dot products than required.

If someone knows of a way to improve on einsum's performance for my use-case I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What are the shapes of U and V?

Comment: Also, you can try `U[:,None,:] @ V[...,None]`.

Comment: The shape depends on data from the user, in my tests I use the shape: (20, 10000)

Comment: What about just `(U * V).sum(1)`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist that's gonna be slower due to overhead for intermediate arrays.

Comment: @Divakar. Looks like your solution wins

Comment: @QuangHoang. What surprised me is that if I use `np.multiply(U, V, out=U).sum(1)`, ~20% slower (same for `out=V`).

Comment: @Divakar I'll check your solution and report back (Adding ravel() to flatten the result)

Comment: Does anyone know if tensorflow, numba, or whatnot would adequately fuse the `(U * V).sum(1)` answer above since OP is doing the same kind of computation to many inputs?

Comment: @Divakar your solution gave me an improvement of 14% on average (20 runs with each implementation) - which is very nice. please post your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it later. I'll wait a little more to see if there are more ideas.

Comment: If that works, we can close as a duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090401/how-to-calculate-the-dot-product-of-two-arrays-of-vectors-in-python. Just added that one there.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does anyone know why np.matmul is faster than np.einsum? is it due to parallelism or something else?